# How to scale a form to full screen using WebView?

Tags: android

I have a form that only takes up a small portion of the page it is on, so in webview it has huge gaps and I need it to be full screen. I figured out how to scale it by zooming to my device but the problem is I need to use this app on multiple devices with many potential screen resolutions. My final goal is to have the form be full screen on any device as soon as you open the app.

Comment: So which is the problem, the content IN the webview isn't full screen or the webview itself isn't full screen?

Comment: Kindly post your xml file.Try setting your webview attributes to  fill_parent and check the result

Comment: I think this problem has to do more with your html then it does webview based on your description can you post up your xml and also the html for the form